# How should i go about creating autolayout for resizing cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, autolayout

Having trouble with getting the constraints right for my storyboard setup in order for the self sizing.

Heres what my storyboard looks like:

The grey background is the cells contentView

The white view on top of that is a UIView and everything like images, labels and buttons are on top of the white UIView

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: give equal width and height to both the button and label and fixed size to the image view

Comment: this isn't really a question, what content will buttons and labels have, and how should things resize? add some constraints and ask about specific issues when you encounter them...

Comment: the buttons and labels just have plain text. The image is what i need to be able to resize according to the image.

Comment: @James i dont want a fixed height for image. i want it to resize according to the image